# Run an application from a newly spawned Alacritty without the window closing after execution

Tags: command-line, nice

I`m trying to open a program from Alacritty with a keybindf without closing the window afterward. (it uses the window to output errors ects)

My command is currently:

```
alacritty -t houdiniTerm -e sudo nice -n -2 su -c /opt/hfs19.5.368/bin/houdini username
```

Currently I enter my password, the application launches, and the terminal window shuts down.  The app keeps running.

Does anyone know if I can keep the window open?

I ended up just running the program from a script

alacritty --hold -e ~/dev/scripts/l_houdini

#!/bin/zsh
houdini
exec zsh

Comment: What is currently happening when you launch that program? You are not providing any information about it.

Comment: Currently i give my password , the application launches and the terminal window shuts down.(app keeps running)

Comment: Please add all information that is useful to understand the problem to the actual question: use "edit".

Comment: answer to my question can be found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution

Comment: @NicTanghe Since you found the answer to your own question, please post that as an *answer* for others to see rather than leaving it in the comments.  You can then self-accept the answer after a certain period of time.  Thanks!

Comment: I found out it didn't work as expected i think the hold answer is the correct one but I've stopped using nice on my program i’ll have a look at this sometime again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 2 scripts.
I had to initialize an environment in between to pass variables as well as keep a window open

desktop:

```
Exec="/home/****/dev/scripts/l_houdini_1.sh" %F
```

here are the scripts.

```
#!/bin/zsh
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
    echo "you passed $1 in first script"
    if [[ "$0" = /* ]]
    then
        p=$1
    else
        p=$(pwd)/$(basename "$1")
    fi

    echo "the file is here: $p"

    alacritty --hold -e /home/****/dev/scripts/l_houdini_2.sh $p
else
    alacritty --hold -e /home/****/dev/scripts/l_houdini_2.sh
fi
```

and then the second one

```
cd /opt/hfs19.5
source ./houdini_setup



export PATH="$PATH:/home/****/tools:/home/****/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/****/tools/flutter/bin:/home/****/.cargo/bin:/home/****/tools/Unreal_5.1_prev1/Engine/Binaries/Linux"
export OCIO='/home/****/CGI/color/OpenColorIO-Configs/aces_1.2/config.ocio'
export __EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_FILENAMES=/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa.json
export HSITE="/home/****/CGI/HSITE"
export XSECURELOCK_PASSWORD_PROMPT= "kaomoji"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/python3.7"

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
    echo "you passed $1 in second script"
    /opt/hfs19.5/bin/hview-bin $1  
    
else
    echo "opening default location"
    houdini
fi


exec zsh
```

Answer (score -1):

See the Alacritty man page for the `--hold` option. I think this is what you're looking for.

Also you might want to open `bash` at the end so if the process is closed Alacritty wouldn't be unusable.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I've edited your answer to focus on the potentially useful parts and removed the unconstructive rants and fluff (*"[Anything that is not relevant to the post is noise and should be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/11810933)"*) to hopefully spare you from more downvotes. Unfortunately not every question here is even *seen* by someone with expertise in the particular app being referenced. With only 62 questions about Alacritty here (out of 399k), Alacritty users aren't exactly flocking here at the moment to ask or answer questions on the topic, it seems.